# Friendly url's in joomla site

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, sef

I am trying to make more friendly the urls of my joomla site. Currently, a typical url is like this:
 **www.mysite.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=5&Itemid=10&hotel=182**.

I would like to have a url like the following:
 **www.mysite.com/hotel_name**, where the value of  hotel_name will be the value of the field 'hotel_name' in my DB! 
What are the required processes in the .htaccess file in order to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

After you turn on SEF, structure of url is set based on router.php file in component's folder. ( com_content/router.php. )

Or you can use component to make your own url http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/sef

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which webserver (Apache, Nginx, etc) you are using there is a tutorial for that 
http://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_Search_Engine_Friendly_%28SEF%29_URLs

Comment: my server is Apache and my pages are not static articles but thet are produced dynamically from data stored in a database